# signal.setitimer with time zero followed by signal.pause not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals

I have the following code and it's working as expected:

```
import signal

def printer(signum, frame):
    print("hi!")

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, printer)
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0.1, 3.0)

while(True):
    signal.pause()
```

I would like to use `signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0.0, 3.0)`, but to timer properly start it needs a little wait: `signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0.1, 3.0)`. What's happening here? Is there a way to start the timer instantly?

(Works only in Linux)

Comment: `help(signal.setitimer)` notes that setting `seconds`, the 2nd arg, to zero will clear the timer. This echoes how the underlying [setitimer](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getitimer.html) system call works. You can give it an arg as small as 1 microsecond,  `0.000001`, if you want.

Comment: perfect. Set as a answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `signal.setitimer` says that if the `seconds` arg is 0, this will clear the timer:

```
setitimer(which, seconds, interval=0.0, /)
    Sets given itimer (one of ITIMER_REAL, ITIMER_VIRTUAL or ITIMER_PROF).

    The timer will fire after value seconds and after that every interval seconds.
    The itimer can be cleared by setting seconds to zero.

    Returns old values as a tuple: (delay, interval).
```

This reflects the behavior of the underlying POSIX [setitimer](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getitimer.html) system call:

```
Setting it_value to 0 shall disable a timer, regardless of the value of it_interval.
```

On POSIX systems, it_value is a [timeval struct](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_time.h.html), which has a precision measured in microseconds. So if you can tolerate a very small delay before the timer first fires, just call setitimer with an arg that's a very small number, as small as 1 microsecond:

```
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0.000001, 3.0)
```